# How to publish a component using SDL Core Services in Java?

Tags: 2011, core-service, sdl-tridion

I am trying to publish a component using core services in Java but on running the code, I am getting this error :-

Exception in thread "main" com.sdltridion.contentmanager.coreservice.ICoreServicePublishCoreServiceFaultFaultFaultMessage: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: publishInstruction.ResolveInstruction.

Here's my code

```
         ReadOptions readOptions = new ReadOptions();

    ArrayOfstring componentsArray=new ArrayOfstring();
    componentsArray.getString().add("tcm:1010-2312-16");


    ArrayOfstring publicationTarget=new ArrayOfstring();
    publicationTarget.getString().add("tcm:0-2-65537");

    PublishInstructionData publishInstructionData = new PublishInstructionData();
    ResolveInstructionData resolveInstructionData = new ResolveInstructionData();
    resolveInstructionData.setIncludeChildPublications(false);


    JAXBElement<ResolvePurpose> resolvePurpose =    new JAXBElement<ResolvePurpose>(new QName("http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/R6","Purpose"), ResolvePurpose.class, ResolvePurpose.PUBLISH);
    resolveInstructionData.setPurpose(resolvePurpose);


    JAXBElement<ResolveInstructionData> jaxbElement =    new JAXBElement<ResolveInstructionData>(new QName("http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2011","com.sdltridion.contentmanager.coreservice._2011.Publish"), ResolveInstructionData.class, resolveInstructionData);
    publishInstructionData.setResolveInstruction(jaxbElement);

     RenderInstructionData renderInstructionData = new RenderInstructionData();


      JAXBElement<RenderMode> renderMode =    new JAXBElement<RenderMode>(new QName("http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/R6","RenderMode"), RenderMode.class, RenderMode.PUBLISH);
      renderInstructionData.setRenderMode(renderMode);

    JAXBElement<RenderInstructionData> renderInstruction =    new JAXBElement<RenderInstructionData>(new QName("http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2011","com.sdltridion.contentmanager.coreservice._2011.Publish"), RenderInstructionData.class, renderInstructionData);



  publishInstructionData.setRenderInstruction(renderInstruction);




      ArrayOfPublishTransactionData ad= endpoint.publish(componentsArray, publishInstructionData, publicationTarget, PublishPriority.LOW, readOptions);
```

Answer (score 6):

Looking at your implementation, publishinstructiondata has two main objects: **ResolveInstructionData** and **RenderInstruction**.

In your implementation, you have created object for ResolveInstructionData however **you are missing RenderInstruction object**. That could be reason the publishing is not working.

Comment: I have already tried adding the RenderInstruction but it did'nt work as I always get the same exception which I have pointed above.

Comment: http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2011","com.sdltridion.contentmanager.coreservice._2011.Publish"

Comment: RenderInstructionData renderInstructionData = new RenderInstructionData();
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  JAXBElement<RenderInstructionData> jaxbElement1 =    new JAXBElement<RenderInstructionData>(new QName("http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2011","com.sdltridion.contentmanager.coreservice._2011.Publish"), RenderInstructionData.class, renderInstructionData);
 


   publishInstructionData.setRenderInstruction(jaxbElement1);

Comment: For `ResolveInstructionData` you also need to `setPurpose`, probably to `ResolvePurpose.PUBLISH`; and for the `RenderInstructionData` you need to set a `RenderMode`, again, probably to `RenderMode.PUBLISH`.  You may also find http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/12/a-core-service-java-client.html useful if you want to unwrap the JAXB elements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dave, but the recommendation by you doesn't seems to work.
I have updated my code and still getting the same error as I have mentioned above.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is mainly a question on how to construct a proper SOAP request in general in Java (using JAXB?)

I recommend to enable WCF Tracing in the Core Service (there are comments in `webservices/web.config` on how to do that).
This allows you to see the SOAP request sent to the Core Service to check what's in there and what's not.

Comment: Well I have already made many SOAP request using JAXB to get the data from the CMS using core-services.
I want to know here, if there's something I am missing or the way of doing this is not correct ??

Comment: The answer to that question is most probably "yes", but I can't tell you what the issue is exactly. I just hope that the WCF Trace helps you analyzing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding this answer here since there was no accepted answer and might help people. The namespace URI and the service name used for the `QName` objects are incorrect for  `ResolvePurpose`, `ResolveInstruction` and `RenderInstruction`.

To get the `publish` to work, I had to use the right namespace URIs and the service names. Something like this should work:

```
public class PublishService {   
    private static final QName RENDER_MODE_Q_NAME = 
                 new QName("http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/R6", "RenderMode");
    private static final QName RESOLVE_PURPOSE_Q_NAME = 
                 new QName("http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/R6", "ResolvePurpose");
    private static final QName RESOLVE_INSTRUCTION_DATA_Q_NAME = 
                 new QName("http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/R6", "ResolveInstruction");
    private static final QName RENDER_INSTRUCTION_DATA_Q_NAME = 
                 new QName("http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/R6", "RenderInstruction");

    public void publish() throws ICoreServiceGetApiVersionCoreServiceFaultFaultFaultMessage, 
                 ICoreServiceGetDefaultDataCoreServiceFaultFaultFaultMessage, 
                 ICoreServiceCreateCoreServiceFaultFaultFaultMessage,
                 ICoreServicePublishCoreServiceFaultFaultFaultMessage  {
        CoreService201603 coreService = new CoreService201603();
        ICoreService coreServiceClient = coreService.getBasicHttp();

        ArrayOfstring targetIdsArrString = new ArrayOfstring();
        targetIdsArrString.getString().add("tcm:0-20-65538");

        List<String> itemsToPublish = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemsToPublish.add("tcm:150-1365-512");

        ArrayOfstring itemsToPublishArrString = new ArrayOfstring();
        itemsToPublishArrString.getString().addAll(itemsToPublish);


        JAXBElement<RenderMode> renderModeJaxElement = 
                new JAXBElement<RenderMode>(RENDER_MODE_Q_NAME, RenderMode.class, RenderMode.PUBLISH);
        RenderInstructionData renderInstructionData = new RenderInstructionData();
        renderInstructionData.setRenderMode(renderModeJaxElement);

        JAXBElement<ResolvePurpose> resolvePurposeJaxElement = 
                new JAXBElement<ResolvePurpose>(RESOLVE_PURPOSE_Q_NAME, ResolvePurpose.class, ResolvePurpose.PUBLISH);
        ResolveInstructionData resolveInstructionData = new ResolveInstructionData();
        resolveInstructionData.setPurpose(resolvePurposeJaxElement);

        JAXBElement<RenderInstructionData> renderInstructionDataJaxElement = 
                new JAXBElement<RenderInstructionData>(RENDER_INSTRUCTION_DATA_Q_NAME, RenderInstructionData.class, renderInstructionData);
        JAXBElement<ResolveInstructionData> resolveInstructionDataJaxElement = 
                new JAXBElement<ResolveInstructionData>(RESOLVE_INSTRUCTION_DATA_Q_NAME, ResolveInstructionData.class, resolveInstructionData);

        PublishInstructionData publishInstructionData = new PublishInstructionData();
        publishInstructionData.setRenderInstruction(renderInstructionDataJaxElement);
        publishInstructionData.setResolveInstruction(resolveInstructionDataJaxElement);

        coreServiceClient.publish(itemsToPublishArrString, publishInstructionData, targetIdsArrString, PublishPriority.NORMAL, new ReadOptions());
    }
}
```

We can view how the SOAP body should look like and the namespaces and the service names to be used by loading up the WSDL in a tool like SoapUI.

[image]

Comment: i tried above given solution but i get this :
Error occurred in web service client initialization : Unable to cast object of type 'Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.BusinessProcessType' to type 'Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.PublishingTarget'.

Comment: You need to be using publishing target TCM IDs and not BPTs. I think you are passing a BPT TCM ID as a parameter to the publish function and not a publishing target (e.g., tcm:x-xx-65538).