# Tridion Java/Node/Python API to create and publish a new taxonomy programmatically

Tags: java, taxonomy

I need to create and publish a new taxonomy that has more than around 1000 entries. This a laborious task if I have to do it manually.

I'm new to the technology and community. So, wonder if I can get some help.

I did some research around the topic and found `Tom.Net` API useful. I'm curious if I have any equivalent `Java/Node/Python` API which I'm comfortable at. I also looked at `dd4t-2-java` and `dxa-java`, but could not find any code samples suitable for my requirement.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Tridion, there is another way which might interest you, and that is create JAVASCRIPT client for SDL coreservice.

https://yatb.mitza.net/2018/08/javascript-client-for-coreservice.html

Answer (score 2):

Like Nick mentioned if you are looking for a Java-based solution you'd have to use the Core Service API. The set up is pretty straight forward.

First, create a Java proxy client from the WSDL (e.g., if you are using 8.5 you'd use the WSDL at http://SERVER:PORT/webservices/CoreService201603.svc?wsdl.) The steps for creating the proxy are described here: https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-CF2ABF27-2D1C-4342-9635-2DFD7A6D4D42.

Creating the proxy will create all the required classes for interacting with the Core Service API. Just include these generated classes in your Java classpath of your client and you should be able to create categories and publish them.

To create a category:

```
CoreService201603 coreService = new CoreService201603();
ICoreService coreServiceClient = coreService.getBasicHttp();

// "tcm:0-150-1" is the publication ID where the category is to be created. 
CategoryData categoryData = (CategoryData)coreServiceClient.getDefaultData(ItemType.CATEGORY,
                            "tcm:0-150-1", new ReadOptions());
categoryData.getTitle().setValue("Category 1");
categoryData.getXmlName().setValue("category1");

IdentifiableObjectData category = coreServiceClient.create(categoryData, new ReadOptions());
```

The question here about [How to publish a component using SDL Core Services in Java?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16178/how-to-publish-a-component-using-sdl-core-services-in-java) should help you publish the created categories.

The **full Core Service API documentation** is available for download here: https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-2301148A-E3EA-43EF-A2FC-7D3C9BAEE8FF.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I tried using jax-ws client, I'm getting java.net.SocketException: Connection reset. I guess it is because of credentials. Can you please help me with configuring credentials.

Comment: See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458500/why-am-i-receiving-a-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset-error-from-web-s.

Comment: That didn't unfortunately. It's Akmai, the corporate proxy, blocking these requests. This needs SSO authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Great question! Welcome to the community!
There is a web service API called Core Service which you could use in the language you're comfortable with. But on the CM side, it is .net based and no java/node/python available unless you wrap the Core Service.

Comment: Are there any existing wrappers around the Core service written in these languages.